# Measure convergence and pointwise convergence in almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, pointwise-convergence, borel-sets

im in a trouble. I want to prove a proposition about Lebesgue integral, it would be great if the following were true:

I have the definition of measure convergence of a functions sequence on E:

$ \forall e>0\forall d>0 $ exist N such that:
$ n≥N \implies m(${$x\in E:|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|≥e$})<d

The doubt that I have is
Can I say $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_{n}=f$ in almost all points?

In other words
If A:={x$\in E:(lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_{n})(x)≠f(x)$}
Then m(A)=0?

Thanks <2+1

Comment: This is not true. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415891/almost-everywhere-convergence-versus-convergence-in-measure

Comment: Also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2479451/491675) formulated in probabilistic terms